# How to insert random default image into database with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing a Laravel application.Its have a form which have image upload field and its also not a required field. Now i want to do if anyone submitting form without uploading image then a default random image will be inserted into database from `public/images/default` directory. How can i do that with Laravel? I have 10 images of that directory *(ex: 1b.png, 2b.png, 3b.png....)*

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route($base_route.'.eventEdit', ['event_id' => $event->event_code]) }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="general_form" novalidate="novalidate">
     <input name="name" type="text" value="something" class="name">
     <input name="name" type="file" value="DefaultImageName"  class="image">
     <button class="btn btn-default"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: you need to post your laravel code here.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your controller action

```
$images = scandir(public_path('images/default'));
$image = $request->file('DefaultImageName', $images[mt_rand(0, count($images -1))]);
```

Comment: if anyone add images then you code will work or not?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud, will work, $images  - all images in your default folder. See http://php.net/manual/ru/function.scandir.php

Answer (score 0):

I would't advise storing images in the database. The approach I take is usually, I store in the database a name, alias and path to the file.

You can do this depending on the pattern you're using on the application, but for your situation, what I'd do is create a mutator that validates whenever you're going to insert a record, if certain field is empty, it does something (if you're using eloquent I assume).

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators

```
public function setImageAttribute($value)
{    
   if (empty($value)) {
    $this->attributes['image'] = //fetch your image and apply your logic
   } else { 
    $this->attributes['image'] = value;
   }

}
```

Otherwise, I'd create a formrequest that validates if a certain field is empty, I place some content in it (and this way, when it reaches the insertion code it already contains an image)

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation